# Number of RAM Accesses using Paging on a 32bit processor

Tags: operating-system, paging, ram, 32-bit, memory-access

[Paging Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrYx2.png)

Assuming we use a 32bit Processor with Paging as its memory management scheme. My question is what is the range of possible accesses it might need in order to find the physical adress.

My answer is 0 to 3.

First, it will look for the virtual address in the TLB if it is there then we have 0 accesses.

If it is not there then with the first 10 bits it will do 1 access in the page directory. After it will check the L1 cache with this PDE, if it finds it then we have 1 access in total.

Otherwise, it will move to the page table (according to the PDE) and it will do another memory access based on the second 10 bits of the virtual address. Then it will check the L2 cache with this PTE, if it finds then we 2 RAM accesses in total.

At, last it will use the last 12 bits (the offset) in order to access the RAM in the wanted physical address, giving us 3 accesses in total.

Is the above rationale correct? I am not familiar on how we use L1 and L2 cache.

Thanks

Comment: What's the feedback on the negative vote me question received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the above rationale correct?

It's mostly correct, there's just one subtlety you've overlooked...

> My question is what is the range of possible accesses it might need in order to **find the physical address**.

> Otherwise, it will move to the page table (according to the PDE) and it will do another memory access based on the second 10 bits of the virtual address.

At this point it has the physical address; so the answer is "0 to 2 accesses".

What happens after it already has the physical address (if the data at that address is cached or becomes a 3rd access) doesn't change the answer.

Comment: So your correction is that in order to find the physical adress we actually need 0-2 accesses and the potential 3rd access concerns the retrieving of the data? Also, the caches, do they map the virtual address to the physical address or do they map the vitual address directly to the content/data of the physical adress? Because if they map the virtual adress to the physical address then we always have to do a RAM access for the retrieval.

Comment: @DontWorry: Yes (the third access happens after the physical address is determined). Normally there's TLBs (Translation Look-aside Buffers) that cache translations but are almost never called "caches", and also "caches" (for caching instructions and data). For whether caches use virtual or physical addresses, it depends on the CPU and which cache. Most are "physically indexed, physically tagged" (as it avoids problems with the same physical memory being mapped at many different virtual addresses) where you have to know the physical address to find anything in the cache.

Comment: Ok thanks. So if we modify a bit my initial question to how many RAM accesses we would need with paging in order not only to find the physical address but also read the data then the answer would be 1 to 3, right?

Comment: @DontWorry: If you modify the question like that, it'd be "0 to 3" (as everything could be in TLB and cache).

Comment: Sorry for keep asking its just that with each answer I get different questionmarks. So if we find the physical address in the TLB then which cache do we check for the instruction and data in order to haev 0 accesses? What do L1 and L2 caches map (physical adresses to data/instructions)?

Comment: @DontWorry: It depends on the CPU. For modern 80x86, if it's a data access; once the CPU has the physical address it might check L1 data cache, then L2 shared cache, then L3 shared cache; then (if it wasn't in any caches) the CPU might ask the memory controller to fetch it from RAM.

Comment: @DontWorry: Of course different CPUs are different. E.g. L1 instruction cache might use a mixture of virtual address and physical address, and have extra special stuff built-in to keep track of the start of each instruction to help decoding.